# Table Headers as Labels in Cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get table headers to act as a label within their column's cells using JQuery.

I have this:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="field-title">Title</th>
         <th class="field-name">Name</th>
         <th class="field-last">Last Name</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="field-title">Mr.</th>
         <td class="field-name">John</th>
         <td class="field-last">Doe</th>
      </tr>
   <tbody>
</table>
```

And what I want JQuery to do is place labels for each cell under that column according to the text in the column header.

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="field-title">Title</th>
         <th class="field-name">Name</th>
         <th class="field-last">Last Name</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="field-title"><strong>Title:</strong> Mr.</th>
         <td class="field-name"><strong>Name:</strong> John</th>
         <td class="field-last"><strong>Last Name:</strong> Doe</th>
      </tr>
   <tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way in Js

```js
const ths = document.querySelectorAll("tr th[class]");
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("tr td[class]");

for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  const label = "<strong>" + ths[i%ths.length].textContent + ": " + "</strong>";
  tds[i].innerHTML = label + tds[i].textContent;
}
```

Comment: What if I had another row of cells? The label is only applied to the first row.

Comment: i made a little change for this

Comment: Nice! Thank you!